# Looping through SOAP array Object response

Tags: java, soap, arraylist

After I getting my response in `SOAP` I have as a result `Object` like this:

```
Object result = envelope.getResponse();
```

`result` :[['1/10/2014 11:10:00 PM',1.5,2.2,55.9],['10/10/2014 12:30:00 AM',88.88,88.12,88.99],.....]

casting it to `SoapObject` throws :

```
"java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive"

SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse(); // throws error
```

So I tried:

```
SoapPrimitive resultsString = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
```

and I getting a result the same `result` Object.

**ADDED**: tried `SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;`
and got a result:

```
GetCodesResponse{GetCodesResult=[['1/10/2014 11:10:00 PM',1.5,2.2,55.9]....];}
```

It all return `String` , and I don't have an option to iterate through it.
How can I run loop through `result`, create an Object type `MyCustomClass` with the contractor `MyCustomClass(Data d,double a, double b, double c)` from each Array element and insert  them into `ArrayList<MyCustom>`

Comment: Could you post exception message?

Comment: Did you try to use `SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;` instead of `(SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799775/ksoap2-android-cast-class-exception-soapobject

Comment: It return something like that : GetCodesResponse{GetCodesResult=[['1/10/2014 11:10:00 PM',1.5,2.2,55.9]....];}

Comment: Possible that you should use `HttpPost` and `DefaultHttpClient`. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167341/how-to-pass-json-array-as-parameter-to-a-webservice-using-ksoap2-in-android

Comment: Why? if I getting the result, the problem is just parsing it currect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58164/discussion-between-vartlok-and-dima).